# Campo auto incrementado con stored procedure se repite

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo un problema con mi sistema ya que auto genero un código auto incrementado en Mysql el cual funciona bien cuando el sistema lo usa un solo usuario al usarlo 2 o 3 usuarios este código que genero automáticamente se me repita 3 veces desde su primera creación hasta que el ultimo usuario allá generado su venta.

Para insertar la venta tengo lo siguiente en mi mysql:

```
BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO venta(idtipodocumento,idcliente,idempleado,serie,numero,fecha,totalventa,igv,totalpagar,estado,descuento)
        VALUES(pidtipodocumento,pidcliente,pidempleado,pserie,pnumero,pfecha,ptotalventa,pigv,ptotalpagar,pestado,pdescuento);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as idventa;
END
```

Para obtener el ultimo ID de venta

```
BEGIN

    SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING( MAX( SUBSTRING(Numero, 2) ),5),UNSIGNED INTEGER ) AS id 
    FROM venta
    WHERE 1;
                            END
```

este código en php me muestra el ultimo id y me genera uno nuevo

```
public function generarNumVenta($idtipodoc=1) {

    $con = new clsConexion;
    if($con->conectarse()==true){
        $query = "CALL SP_S_UltimoIdVenta($idtipodoc)";
        $result = @mysql_query($query);
        while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $ultimo_id_venta=$array['id']+1;
        }

    }
    $strNum_venta=str_pad((int) $ultimo_id_venta,10,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return $strNum_venta;

}
```

El problema es que cuando hay mas de un usuario generando ventas este código se auto repite y es no lo quiero quiero que si hay 3 usuarios generando ventas este automáticamente se auto genere ejemplo 0000000001, 0000000002, 0000000003 
en la próxima venta 3 usuarios mas generaron 3 ventas 0000000004, 0000000005, 0000000006 y así seguidamente.

Me disculpan tanto el enredo de pronto alguien pudiera dar una mejor pregunta para obtener la mejor respuesta en la comunidad, un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es por la concurrencia cuando tu procedimiento se ejecuta por mas de un usuario devuelve el mismo numero ya que no ha habido cambios e la tabla  y `CONVERT(SUBSTRING( MAX( SUBSTRING(Numero, 2) ),5),UNSIGNED INTEGER )` es el mismo, para solucionarlo te recomiendo estas opciones.

1. El procedimiento de que obtiene el ultimo id de venta grabe una venta sin los datos, confirme la transacción y luego la modifiques para que cuando llegue la siguiente consulta de el `max (numero)` ya haya cambiado.
2. Crea una tabla aparte donde guardes el ultimo id de venta y la serie por documento y ahí modifiques el valor del ultimo id de venta.
3. Te bases en el autoincremental de la tabla factura para generar el id de venta.

4.También puede intentar hacer la consulta `CONVERT(SUBSTRING( MAX( SUBSTRING(Numero, 2) ),5),UNSIGNED INTEGER )` en el mismo insert

Te recomiendo la segunda opción ya que tendrás mas control de tus series, la primera no te la recomiendo ya que tendrás que borrar las facturas de las transacciones que salgan mal y tratas de usar transacciones no funcionara ya que mientras no se confirmen las demás sesiones no pueden ver los cambios por lo que tendrás el mismo problema.

Comment: Gracias por su explicación me sirvió de mucho saludos.!